# How to convert datetime() to timestamp() in Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang

I need to convert `{{2012, 9, 21}, {13, 21, 11}}` into `timestamp()`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825151/convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-erlang

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Corrected version:

```
Seconds = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(DateTime) - 62167219200,
%% 62167219200 == calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{1970, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})
{Seconds div 1000000, Seconds rem 1000000, 0}.
```

Comment: It is ok, but beware that if you are using the function erlang:now() to get a timestamp for comparison or any calculation, if will give you a time estimation starting on 1/1/1970, while calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1 makes the evaluation from 1/1/0. So there is a difference of 719528 days...

Comment: Oops, you are right. And since `timestamp()` is defined as starting from 1970 if possible, my answer was _not_ ok :)

Comment: I have tried the function above: Timestamp = datetime_to_now({{2012, 9, 21}, {13, 21, 00}}) then calendar:now_to_local_time(Timestamp) returns {{2012,9,21},{17,21,0}}. My timezone is +4h. As I can understand the function returns timestamp in UTC. Right?

Comment: @KirillTrofimov Yes, just like timestamp returned by `now/0`. If you need local time, convert it using `calendar:local_time_to_universal_time_dst/1` first.

Answer (score 2):

You might use this

```
to_timestamp({{Year,Month,Day},{Hours,Minutes,Seconds}}) ->
(calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(
    {{Year,Month,Day},{Hours,Minutes,Seconds}}
) - 62167219200)*1000000;
```

This is part of module from this 
[Github/Arboreus](https://github.com/ArboreusLibrary/Fw_library/blob/master/src/universal/a_time.erl)