# sending time in UTC format from ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, utc, mnesia

I am sending a xmpp message to client from server(ejabberd).This message contains a field which contains  date(Basically seconds since 1970) in UTC format.How to get a date in UTC format in erlang?Any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#universal_time-0) `calendar:universal_time/0`

```
universal_time() -> datetime()

datetime() = {date(), time()}
date() = {year(), month(), day()}
time() = {hour(), minute(), second()}
```

Like this

```
{Date, _Time} = DateTime = calendar:universal_time()
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527908/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-in-erlang) question to convert `datetime()` to unix timestamp. You'll just need to convert timestamp to seconds since 1970/01/01:

```
Seconds = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(DateTime) - 62167219200,
%% 62167219200 == calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{1970, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})
```

Comment: @Geek then first state in your question that you ask for date in seconds since 1970 to begin with.

Comment: I have modified the question :).